# AppEngine ChannelAPI WARNING: No file found for: /_ah/channel/connected/

Tags: java, google-app-engine, channel-api

in my web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>channelConnected</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ChannelConnected</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>channelConnected</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/channel/connected</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

my servlet

```
public class ChannelConnected extends HttpServlet{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
            throws ServletException, IOException{
          System.out.println("hello world");
    }

}
```

I always get this error:

```
WARNING: No file found for: /_ah/channel/connected/
```

What's wrong with my request handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding backslash to the url pattern make it work.

```
<url-pattern>/_ah/channel/connected/</url-pattern>
```